# how to create 3 objects of a singleton class and call it 6 times but if we calling it 4th time, the first object should be displayed and so on

Tags: java

A class with a `getInstance` method to create MySingleton object

```
public class MySingleton {

    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MySingleton[] arr = new MySingleton[3];
        arr[0] = new MySingleton();
        arr[1] = new MySingleton();
        arr[2] = new MySingleton();
        System.out.println(arr[counter].getInstance());
    }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() {

        if (counter < 3) {
              counter++;
            } else {
              counter = 0;
            }
        return new MySingleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a singleton. Also, a `getInstance()` returning an `int` instead of an instance of the class is... weird. As is the idea that you can have different instances of a singleton. You should do a bit more reading about the singleton pattern.

Comment: Sorry...my bad. I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter variable, starting at zero. Every time it's called you increment the counter, when counter == 2 you set it back to zero.
You also need an array of 3 positions, where each singleton is at one position.
Every time you invoke the singleton that is at counter position.

```
// first:
MySingleton[] arr = new MySingleton[3];
arr[0] = new MySingleton();
arr[1] = new MySingleton();
arr[2] = new MySingleton();


// then:
if (counter < 3) {
  counter++;
} else {
  counter = 0;
}

// invoking
arr[counter].method();
```

Comment: I tried it but its creating a single object. I have updated the code.

Comment: Well that's because it's a Singleton. A Singleton is supposed to only have one instance always.

Comment: see [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-design-pattern/) for more information.

Comment: Right... but my requirement is...i need three new instances for three calls and if the fourth call is made, it should return the first instance, 5th time if its called, it should return the second instance, 6th time, 3rd instance, 7th time, first instance again and so on...let me know if i m not clear.

Comment: Well it can't be 3 singletons. A singleton can only have one instance by definition. Are you sure they have to be singletons? If that's the case, then the assignment is incorrect as it's impossible to complete.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
i assuming that you will never access more than the Long's max value times.

the lazy method:

```java
    private static Map<Long, MySingleton> INSTANCE_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static AtomicLong i = new AtomicLong(0);
    private static final int OBJECT_NUM = 3;

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        long t = i.getAndIncrement();
        return INSTANCE_MAP.computeIfAbsent(t % OBJECT_NUM, () -> new MySingleton());
    }
```

the hungry method:

```java
    private static Map<Long, MySingleton> INSTANCE_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        INSTANCE_MAP.put(0, new MySingleton());
        INSTANCE_MAP.put(1, new MySingleton());
        INSTANCE_MAP.put(2, new MySingleton());
    }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        long t = i.getAndIncrement();
        return INSTANCE_MAP.get(t % OBJECT_NUM);
    }
```

Comment: Thanx @ggbond. The method computeIfAbsent(t % OBJECT_NUM, () -> new MySingleton()); is not applicable here. May be I have to try some other method.

Comment: sure , you can use initialized hashMap, i reedit the anwser

Comment: tried but no go...i have commented earlier on the requirement that i m working. Plz check if that might help.